# Angular Form Validation $invalid not working

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation

I was trying to disable the submit button, when the fields are empty. But its not working. Don't know why its not working. Saw many blogs, but could't figure whats the issue.

```
<form name="createForm">
     <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="createName">Student</label>
      <select class="form-control" name="student" id="createName" ng-
      model="createStudent.studentId" ng-options="item.name for item in 
       allStudent"  required>
      <option value="" selected disabled>Select</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="createClass">Class</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="class" id="createClass" ng-
     model="createStudent.classId" ng-options="item.number for item in 
     allClass"  required>
      <option value="" selected disabled>Select</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-6 text-md-center">
    <label for="createCategory">Type of Category</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="category" id="createCategory" 
     ng-model="createStudent.type" ng-options="item.category_type for 
      item in allcategoriestypes" required>
      <option value="" selected disabled>Select</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row align-items-end justify-content-center">
  <div class="form-group col-md-6 text-md-center">
    <label for="createTeacherName">Teacher Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="teacher" 
     id="createTeacherName" ng-model="createStudent.name" 
     placeholder="Enter Teacher Name" required>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="text-center pt-1">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info px-5" ng-
  click="create(createStudent)" ng-
  disabled="createForm.$invalid">Save</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Please check plunker in my answer below

Comment: I checked, in my project its not working.

Comment: whats the issue ?

Comment: I was loading the form using ng-include. I removed the ng-include and loaded the form directly, now its working.

Comment: oh ok. but i guess my plunker was working ? you unaccepted my answer though it was working.

Comment: I had accepted your answer.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the working plunker for your code :

http://plnkr.co/edit/H1LOahFNWRXYHWTVmrcW?p=preview

```
 <form name="createForm">
     <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="createName">Student</label>
      <select class="form-control" name="student" id="createName" ng-
      model="createStudent.studentId"  required>
       <option value="studentValue">Student Name</option>
    </select>
  </div><br/>
  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="createClass">Class</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="class" id="createClass" ng-
     model="createStudent.classId"  required>
       <option value="classValue">Class</option>
    </select>
  </div><br/>
  <div class="form-group col-md-6 text-md-center">
    <label for="createCategory">Type of Category</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="category" id="createCategory" 
     ng-model="createStudent.type" required>
      <option value="typeValue">Category</option>
    </select>
  </div><br/>
<div class="row align-items-end justify-content-center">
  <div class="form-group col-md-6 text-md-center">
    <label for="createTeacherName">Teacher Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="teacher" 
     id="createTeacherName" ng-model="createStudent.name" 
     placeholder="Enter Teacher Name" required>
  </div>
</div><br/>
<div class="text-center pt-1">
<label>Value returned for $invalid :: {{createForm.$invalid}}</label><br/><br/>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info px-5" ng-click="create(createStudent)" ng-disabled="createForm.$invalid">Save</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Make sure all your tags are properly closed and none of your fields are empty.

Answer (score 2):

it is working fine.it disable the submit button, when the fields are empty.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<form name="createForm">
     <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="createName">Student</label>
      <select class="form-control" name="student" id="createName" ng-
      model="createStudent.studentId" ng-options="item.name for item in 
       allStudent"  required>
      <option value="" selected disabled>Select</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="createClass">Class</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="class" id="createClass" ng-
     model="createStudent.classId" ng-options="item.number for item in 
     allClass"  required>
      <option value="" selected disabled>Select</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-6 text-md-center">
    <label for="createCategory">Type of Category</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="category" id="createCategory" 
     ng-model="createStudent.type" ng-options="item.category_type for 
      item in allcategoriestypes" required>
      <option value="" selected disabled>Select</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row align-items-end justify-content-center">
  <div class="form-group col-md-6 text-md-center">
    <label for="createTeacherName">Teacher Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="teacher" 
     id="createTeacherName" ng-model="createStudent.name" 
     placeholder="Enter Teacher Name" required>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="text-center pt-1">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info px-5" ng-
  click="create(createStudent)" ng-
  disabled="createForm.$invalid">Save</button>
</div>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: No. Don't know why its not working. In other page its working.

Comment: When I add form name like this {{createForm}}, its undefined.

Comment: I figure out the issue, to the load the form I had used ng-include. When I remove the ng-include and load the form directly its working.